# pandas: error on DataFrame.unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote the following function to convert several columns of a dataframe into numeric values:

```
def factorizeMany(data, columns):
    """ Factorize a bunch of columns in a data frame"""
    data[columns] = data[columns].stack().rank(method='dense').unstack()
    return data
```

Calling it like this

```
trainDataPre = factorizeMany(trainDataMerged.fillna(0), columns=["char_{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,10)])
```

gives me an error. I don't know where to look for the cause, possibly wrong input?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-357f8a4b2ef8> in <module>()
      1 #trainDataPre = trainDataMerged.drop(["people_id", "activity_id", "date"], axis=1)
      2 #trainDataPre = trainDataMerged.fillna(0)
----> 3 trainDataPre = mininggear.factorizeMany(trainDataMerged.fillna(0), columns=["char_{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,10)])

/Users/cls/Dropbox/Datengräber/Kaggle/RedHat/mininggear.py in factorizeMany(data, columns)
     15 def factorizeMany(data, columns):
     16     """ Factorize a bunch of columns in a data frame"""
---> 17     data[columns] = data[columns].stack().rank(method='dense').unstack()
     18     return data
     19 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   2041         """
   2042         from pandas.core.reshape import unstack
-> 2043         return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   2044 
   2045     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.py in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    405     else:
    406         unstacker = _Unstacker(obj.values, obj.index, level=level,
--> 407                                fill_value=fill_value)
    408         return unstacker.get_result()
    409 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.py in __init__(self, values, index, level, value_columns, fill_value)
     90 
     91         # when index includes `nan`, need to lift levels/strides by 1
---> 92         self.lift = 1 if -1 in self.index.labels[self.level] else 0
     93 
     94         self.new_index_levels = list(index.levels)

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your `trainDataMerged` dataframe?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso Post a huge CSV string? What if that sample doesn't contain the data that causes the error? As the answer below shows, this question can be answered with some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you are trying to perform the `rank` operation on the subset of the dataframe containing both numerical and categorical/string values by filling the `NaN's` in the dataframe with 0 and calling that function.

Consider this case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'char_1': ['cat', 'dog', 'buffalo', 'cat'],
                   'char_2': ['mouse', 'tiger', 'lion', 'mouse'],
                   'char_3': ['giraffe', np.NaN, 'cat', np.NaN]})
df
```

[image]

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df[['char_3']].stack().rank()
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

So, you are basically performing the `unstack` operation on an empty series which is not what you wanted to do after all.

Better is to do this way to avoid further complications:

```
def factorizeMany(data, columns):
    """ Factorize a bunch of columns in a data frame"""
    stacked = data[columns].stack(dropna=False)
    data[columns] = pandas.Series(stacked.factorize()[0], index=stacked.index).unstack()
    return data
```

Comment: Sorry, switching the order of the `factorizeMany` and `fillna` alone still produces the error.

Comment: Also, `stack` method drops all `NaN` values present by default. So, you might want to use `stack(dropna=False)` to feed it to `factorize` method which marks them as -1.